# PIP-installed global script throws exception, local copy works flawlessly

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, importerror, pypi

I've just registered my new package with `PIP`

```
python setup.py register
python setup.py sdist upload
```

And I wanted to install it on other machine globally (i.e. no virtualenv) using 'PIP':

```
sudo pip install standardiser
```

This all went fine, since I have one file registered as a script:

```
setup(
...
scripts=['standardiser/bin/standardiser.py'],
)
```

'standariser.py' is now available as CLI command system wide. But if I execute it, I'm getting:

```
mnowotka@candela:~/Documents/ci/curation_interface/trunk/src$ standardiser.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/standardiser.py", line 32, in <module>
    from standardiser import standardise, SDF
  File "/usr/local/bin/standardiser.py", line 32, in <module>
    from standardiser import standardise, SDF
ImportError: cannot import name standardise
```

I get the same when I explicitly call python:

```
python /usr/local/bin/standardiser.py
```

But if I copy this to some local folder:

```
sudo cp python /usr/local/bin/standardiser.py bla.py
```

And run it from there:

```
mnowotka@candela:~$ python bla.py
usage: bla.py [-h] [-V] [-r] infile
bla.py: error: too few arguments
```

I don't have any `ImportEror`s. What I'm doing wrong? Can you help me?

My setyp.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__author__ = 'mnowotka'

import sys

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from ez_setup import use_setuptools
    use_setuptools()
    from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='standardiser',
    version='0.1.4',
    author='Francis Atkinson',
    author_email='francis@ebi.ac.uk',
    description='Provides a simple way of standardising molecules as a prelude to e.g. molecular modelling exercises.',
    url='https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/index.php/ws',
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    scripts=['standardiser/bin/standardiser.py'],
    packages=['standardiser'],
    long_description=open('ReadMe.txt').read(),
    package_data={
        'standardiser': ['bin/*', 'data/*', 'docs/*', 'knime/*', 'test/*',],
        },
    classifiers=['Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
                 'Environment :: Console',
                 'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
                 'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
                 'Operating System :: OS Independent',
                 'Programming Language :: Python',
                 'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Chemistry'],
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a script to be installed named `standardiser.py`; that script (at least, the one you've uploaded to the cheese shop) contains the line:

```
from standardiser import standardise, SDF
```

But thats an ambigious import; the script you're executing, `/usr/local/bin/standardise.py` appears in sys.path, because the main script is located there.  it's importing *itself*!

you should be using the `console_scripts` feature of setuptools anyway.

alter your script file from

```
#! /guess/path/to python
from standardise import import *
do_things()
do_more_things()
```

to

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from standardise import import *

def main():
    do_things()
    do_more_things()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which is to say;

- get rid of the shebang; you never need it in python!
- use the `absolute_import` feature to get the module named `foo.bar.foo` to be able to import `foo` instead of only `foo.bar.foo` (you can still import `foo.bar.foo` as either `from foo.bar import foo` or `import .foo`).  `__future__` imports must appear first in the source file, before any other non-comment lines (including other imports)
- most importantly; wrap import time side effects in a function, and only invoke those side effects if this is the "main script"

then change your `setup.py` around from

```
setup(
    scripts=['standardiser/bin/standardiser.py'],
    ...)
```

to

```
setup(
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'standardiser=standardiser.bin.standardiser:main']},
    ...)
```

which is to say:

- use an entry point; setuptools knows how to get your installed package on `sys.path` correctly in this case, and it knows how to connect to the proper python interpreter, the one that was used to run `setup.py`.  This matters when there are multiple versions of python, or when running in a virtualenv.  this is *why* you never need a shebang.
- remove the '.py' from the installed executable name.  this shouldn't ever be there for scripts that are to be on your executable path.